# imported .obj isn't showing in view port

Tags: import

my imported .obj ( https://we.tl/t-fYIpf9R6z0 ) isn't showing in the view port. I've played around with scale and tried scaling the point up and down but still no luck.

[image: using blender for Mac btw]

I'm really new to blender so any step by step advice would be super helpful.

Comment: According to your image (right bottom side) there is no object at all, no faces, no edges, no vertex.

Comment: ah okay. thats probably something to do with when im exporting it from rhino right?